# Have div inside a th element be same height as the parent th element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="height:100px;background-color:red">
                  <div>numbers</div>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:orange">
                  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;">animals</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>5.0</td>
                <td>cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7.0</td>
                <td>dog</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Also see this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0TKcvlauVMAxp69qFovy?p=preview

I want to get the div in the second cell to be the same height as the th element (so all green). I did some research and it seems like `height:100%` only works if the parent th element has an explicitly defined height. Is there a way to get what I want by only changing the css of the div in the second cell? (I can't change the style of the parent `th` element, and don't want to use javascript/jquery)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mJBsdhi47RRNveOUuRY2?p=preview height: 100% works

Comment: @connexo not on chrome it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no css solutions in your case.
Only absolute positioned child elements can inherit height from parent without setting height on parent.

You should use script or change your template to solve it.

**upd:**
How about this solution for you? (you can set 100% height on div:before)

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                  <div>numbers<br> test <br>test</div>
              </th>
                <th>
                  <div id="test">animals</div>
            </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>5.0</td>
                <td>cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7.0</td>
                <td>dog</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <style>
      #test:before{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background: #f00;
        content: '';
        z-index: -1;
      }
      th{
          position: relative;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is only about plain bg color, then a pseudo element can do the job

```css
th {/* prepare th to hold a hudge pseudo element*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullbg {/* make pseudo's continer the positioning reference */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;/* set over the th , useful for the pseudo coming */
}

.fullbg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;/* make it big enough  1000px won't hurt here */
  width: 200px;
  background: inherit;/* inherit bg color you want */
  z-index: -1;/* set under content */
  top: -100px;/* slide aside top and left to fully cover th */
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
 <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="height:100px;background-color:red">
                  <div>numbers</div>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:orange">
                  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;" class="fullbg">animals</div>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:orange">
                  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:turquoise;" class="fullbg">family</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>5.0</td>
                <td>cat</td>
                <td>cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7.0</td>
                <td>dog</td>
                <td>dog</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```